# Pyspark Create New Categoric Column Based on a New Condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My input spark data frame is;

```
    Year  Month        Client  Value 
    2019  1            1       5 
    2019  2            1       3  
    2019  3            1       4  
    2019  4            1       0  
    2019  5            1       3  
    2019  6            1       15 
    2019  7            1       45 
    2019  8            1       50 
    2019  9            1       64  
    2019  10           1       91   
    2019  11           1       1 
    2019  12           1       34  
    2019  1            2       0 
    2019  2            2       0  
    2019  3            2       0  
    2019  4            2       0  
    2019  5            2       1  
    2019  6            2       2 
    2019  7            2       10 
    2019  8            2       1 
    2019  9            2       4  
    2019  10           2       7 
    2019  11           2       1 
    2019  12           2       34
```

Dataframe is ordered by client, year, and month.

"Target" column is 3 if the maximum value in the last 6 months (from 2019-06 to 2019-12) is greater than 90.

"Target" column is 2 if the maximum value in the last 6 months (from 2019-06 to 2019-12) is greater than 15 and less than 90.

"Target" column is 1 if the maximum value in the last 6 months (from 2019-06 to 2019-12) is less than 15.

I shared the desired output according to the data above;

```
    Year  Month        Client  Value Target
    2019  1            1       5     3
    2019  2            1       3     3
    2019  3            1       4     3
    2019  4            1       0     3 
    2019  5            1       3     3
    2019  6            1       15    3
    2019  7            1       45    3 
    2019  8            1       50    3
    2019  9            1       64    3 
    2019  10           1       91    3
    2019  11           1       1     3
    2019  12           1       34    3
    2019  1            2       0     2
    2019  2            2       0     2
    2019  3            2       0     2
    2019  4            2       0     2
    2019  5            2       1     2
    2019  6            2       2     2
    2019  7            2       10    2
    2019  8            2       1     2
    2019  9            2       4     2
    2019  10           2       7     2
    2019  11           2       1     2
    2019  12           2       34    2
```

Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the relevant rows using `row_number`, get the maximum value and thus the target, and join it back to the original dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'rn', 
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('Client').orderBy(F.desc('year'), F.desc('month')))
).filter('rn <= 7').drop('rn').groupBy('Client').agg(
    F.when(F.max('Value') > 90, 3)
     .when(F.max('Value') > 15, 2)
     .otherwise(1)
     .alias('Target')
).join(df, 'Client').select(*df.columns, 'Target')

df2.show(99)
+----+-----+------+-----+------+
|Year|Month|Client|Value|Target|
+----+-----+------+-----+------+
|2019|    1|     1|    5|     3|
|2019|    2|     1|    3|     3|
|2019|    3|     1|    4|     3|
|2019|    4|     1|    0|     3|
|2019|    5|     1|    3|     3|
|2019|    6|     1|   15|     3|
|2019|    7|     1|   45|     3|
|2019|    8|     1|   50|     3|
|2019|    9|     1|   64|     3|
|2019|   10|     1|   91|     3|
|2019|   11|     1|    1|     3|
|2019|   12|     1|   34|     3|
|2019|    1|     2|    0|     2|
|2019|    2|     2|    0|     2|
|2019|    3|     2|    0|     2|
|2019|    4|     2|    0|     2|
|2019|    5|     2|    1|     2|
|2019|    6|     2|    2|     2|
|2019|    7|     2|   10|     2|
|2019|    8|     2|    1|     2|
|2019|    9|     2|    4|     2|
|2019|   10|     2|    7|     2|
|2019|   11|     2|    1|     2|
|2019|   12|     2|   34|     2|
+----+-----+------+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out all months before June and get maximal value for each client:

```
(
    df.filter(F.col('Month') >= 6)
    .groupby('Client')
    .agg(F.when(F.max('Value') > 90, 3)
         .when(F.max('Value') > 15, 2)
         .otherwise(1)
         .alias('Target'))
    .join(df, 'Client')
    .select(*df.columns, 'Target')
).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+-----+------+-----+------+
|Year|Month|Client|Value|Target|
+----+-----+------+-----+------+
|2019|    1|     1|    5|     3|
|2019|    2|     1|    3|     3|
|2019|    3|     1|    4|     3|
|2019|    4|     1|    0|     3|
|2019|    5|     1|    3|     3|
|2019|    6|     1|   15|     3|
|2019|    7|     1|   45|     3|
|2019|    8|     1|   50|     3|
|2019|    9|     1|   64|     3|
|2019|   10|     1|   91|     3|
|2019|   11|     1|    1|     3|
|2019|   12|     1|   34|     3|
|2019|    1|     2|    0|     2|
|2019|    2|     2|    0|     2|
|2019|    3|     2|    0|     2|
|2019|    4|     2|    0|     2|
|2019|    5|     2|    1|     2|
|2019|    6|     2|    2|     2|
|2019|    7|     2|   10|     2|
|2019|    8|     2|    1|     2|
+----+-----+------+-----+------+
only showing top 20 rows
```